# Another urn problem - computing optimisation

Tags: probability

The problem goes like this:

> Suppose in a urn we have 6 red ball and 17 green balls, I extract 12
>   balls at random, during this process none of the extracted balls are
>   reinserted into the urn. What is the probability of getting exactly 3
>   red balls among the 12 extracted?

Alright, so I know how to calculate the solution to this problem via a tree diagram. However due to the large amounts of combinations the process of computing it is very tedious. I could just write some code to do it for me, but that isn’t my goal here...

I would like to compute this in a much faster way if it’s possible, I’m guessing it’s most got to do with combinatorics but I can’t seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Thinking of the balls as numbered $\{r_1,\cdots, r_6, g_1, \cdots, g_{17}\}$,  there are $\binom 63\times \binom {17}9$ ways to choose $12$ balls such that exactly $3$ are red.

Comment: @lulu and there are $\binom{23}{12}$ total combinations so the probability of having 3 red balls is $\frac{\binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{17}{9}}{\binom{23}{12}} \approx 0.36$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for the help @lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit goes to the user ‘lulu’ whose contribution can be found on the comments section under my question.

Basically we have $\binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{17}{9}$ ways to choose 12 balls such that 3 are red.

Since there are $\binom{23}{12}$ total combinations, the probability of having 3 red

balls is $\frac{\binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{17}{9}}{\binom{23}{12}} \approx 0.36$

Comment: An upvote for taking the time to answer the question. But you should accept your answer. Otherwise the system thinks that it is still unanswered.

Comment: @miracle173 the system only allows me to accept my own answer after two days from positing it. Therefore I'll accept it when it lets me.